# hidden textbox inside iframe not display when shown in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I have a iframe containing div to be shown later that is initially hidden using a class. When I remove the class from the container div, everything inside it is shown. but textbox inside iframe is not shown.

parent.htm

```
<style>
    .hide
    {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
<script>

    function showSearchWindow(show) {
        if (show) {
            $('div.overlay').removeClass('hide');
        }
        else {
            $('div.overlay').addClass('hide');
        }
    }

</script>

<form id="form1">
<div class='overlay hide'>
    <input type="text" id='txt1' value='test1' />
    <iframe id="frame" src="frame.htm"></iframe>
</div>
<input type="button" id='btnShow' value='Show' onclick='showSearchWindow(true)' />
<input type="button" id='btnHide' value='Hide' onclick='showSearchWindow(false)' />
</form>
```

frame.htm

```
//Reference to jQuery 1.4.1 js file

<form id="form1">
     <input type="text" id='txt2' value='test'/>
</form>
```

when I click 'btnShow', 'txt1' is shown but 'txt2' is not shown.
I did not work in IE 7,8 and 9. in other major browsers it works fine.

Comment: I have tested this code in my IE8, it works fine.

Comment: @e-zinc Yes you ware right. It begin to happen when I refer jQuery js file from frame.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reloading the page after removing the class is the best solution I found so far.

```
function showSearchWindow(show) {
    if (show) {
        $('div.overlay').removeClass('hide');
    $('#frame').attr('src', 'frame.htm');
    }
    else {
        $('div.overlay').addClass('hide');
    $('#frame').attr('src', 'about:blank');
    }
}

<iframe id="frame" src="about:blank"></iframe
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using jQuery?

Calling `$('div.overlay').removeClass('hide')` is not pure javascript.

A solution with pure javascript could look like this:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <style>
    .hide { display: none; }
  </style>
  <script>
    function showSearchWindow(show) {
        document.getElementById("mydiv").className = (show ? "" : "hide");
    }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form id="form1">
   <div class='hide' id='mydiv'>
    <input type="text" id='txt1' value='test1' />
    <iframe id="frame" src="frame.htm"></iframe>
   </div>
   <input type="button" id='btnShow' value='Show' onclick='showSearchWindow(true)' />
   <input type="button" id='btnHide' value='Hide' onclick='showSearchWindow(false)' />
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

The changes I've made is using `document.getElementById("mydiv").className` to set the class name. I also access the div using `id=mydiv` instead of `class=overlay`.

This works in FF9. Hope it helps!

Comment: No. It is not jQuery problem. it seems to be IE bug. What I feel is that IE apply style to all the descendents and when I remove the class, it remove style from only from container and descendents still have that styles applied.